# Can't navigate to the MainWindow

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3, .net-maui

When I navigate to another page in the NavigationView, it works, but when I try to return to the MainWindow by clicking on the selected item, it doesn't work.

Screenshot of the thrown exception:
[image: Screenshot of the thrown exception]

#### Snippet

```cs
private void NavigationViewItem_Tapped(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rootframe.Navigate(typeof(MainWindow));
}
```

Comment: There was *some* page being displayed before your (not shown) "navigation to another page". Find out how your code or xaml refers to that original page. Start in app.xaml.cs - what is shown in line `MainPage = ...;`?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. Here is the pastebin of the App.xaml.cs file. https://pastebin.com/pb12h80W

Comment: You must navigate to a *page* - not a window.

Comment: But my MainWindow.xaml has the xaml design. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot navigate to the main window.  `Frame.NavigateTo()` actually expects a "Page-derived data type".  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate?view=winrt-22621) is especially muddy about it, but it finally states:

> Causes the Frame to load content represented by the specified
> Page-derived data type,...

So, you need to create a new class deriving from Page, put your content there and that's it.

Comment: I have now created a page and when I try to navigate to this page, an error appears. global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: Upon further analysis, it turns out that the error is in the xaml code. I use the devexpress-nuget package, and when I use the charting library, the error is output. If I remove this purpose from the XAML code, the error does not occur. Too bad I really had to create a page and there is no other option. It looks like I can only navigate to the Settings page, but not to the main page, because I have to use the DevExpress nuget on the main page.

Comment: To fix this problem, I need to display the MainWindow as a new window when I click in the NavigationView. How do I this?

Comment: I fixed all the problems. All good! :)